How to maintain a unique constraint across all horizontally sharded PostgreSQL database?
I have a users table like below:
CREATE TABLE users (
  id bigserial primary key,
  email text,
  location text
);

The table is horizontally sharded using location as the key. What should I do if I want email to be unique across all shards? My shards live in different data centers so I'd like to minimize having to go through all them if possible.
I can think of a few options but I'm not sure:

Have a proxy or at the application level query all shards before insert/update, it'll be 2 queries for writes all the time.
Have a table that's replicated across all shards which stores all emails/md5(email) and then within a proxy or at the application level check that table in the nearest shard before insert/update. I think I'd have to do some master-master replication for this, which I'm not too comfortable with.

Is there a way for me to do this with only 1 query and preferably with just PostgreSQL queries (instead of doing something at the application level) so I can keep other parts of my system simple?

What extension you using for sharding? is that citus?
